# Expressjs web app hang after few load

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a express 3 application. After few round of loading the page hang.

The page basically does this 4 steps:

```
 1. Check the session is valid, session is store at redis using express-session and connect-redis
 2. moongose to retrieve record by id
 3. convert one of field data to object, using JSON.parse(data)
 4. res.render the page with the data on step 2
```

I am using Windows, I notice that the memory keep increasing to 1.5 GB of memory, then the server stop functioning.

What is the causes? Memory leak?

Comment: could you share code?

Comment: Now I found out that after I start my application, connected to MongoDB using mongoose, the memory keep increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comments I suggest you to check MongoDB if there is something unusual, maybe you can share it here for a further analysis.

Comment: I found out why, it is not related to MongoDB, it is multer destination is a map share folder.